# Python extract only 'key' values in in nested JSON where 'value' is a dictionary in a list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I have the folowing Json:

```
    {
  "10208": [
    {
      "11003": {
        "totalExecutions": 1,
        "endDate": "",
        "description": "",
        "totalExecuted": 0,
        "started": "",
        "versionName": "v2",
        "expand": "executionSummaries",
        "projectKey": "TEST",
        "versionId": 10208,
        "modifiedBy": "",
        "projectId": 10203,
        "startDate": "",
        "executionSummaries": {
          "executionSummary": []
        }
      },
      "recordsCount": 1
    }
  ],
  "-1": [
    {
      "11005": {
        "totalExecutions": 2,
        "endDate": "",
        "description": "",
        "totalExecuted": 1,
        "started": "",
        "versionName": "Unscheduled",
        "expand": "executionSummaries",
        "modifiedBy": "",
        "projectId": 10203,
        "startDate": "",
        "executionSummaries": {
          "executionSummary": []
        }
      },
      "recordsCount": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to get

> 11003,11005

as output (better if it could be save in csv).this is actually the data i'm getting off a webpage(using requests). super new to Json.. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why do you want "image" and "text" but not "window" and "debug" keys?

Comment: Hey! updated Json to be more specific. those are certain Id's i'm looking for in my json. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your global dictionary has been loaded in `data` you can extract the keys with a comprehension:

```
keys = [k for val in data.values() for d in val for k in d.keys()
    if k != 'recordsCount']
```

And you can easily write them into a csv file with:

```
with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as fdout:
    wr = csv.writer(fdout)
    wr.writerow(keys)
```

Comment: OMG! That's exactly what I was looking for!! thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Use built-in `json.loads(json: str)` to parse json string to python dict.